# Dump doctrine queries count

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In developer mode in Symfony I can see how many queries `EntityManager` do.
How to dump this data?

I try with:

```
$stack = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\DebugStack();
$this->em->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger($stack);
//...queries there
var_dump($stack);
```

Result is wrong:

```
object(Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\DebugStack)[334]
  public 'queries' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'enabled' => boolean true
  public 'start' => null
  public 'currentQuery' => int 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All SQL queries are logged in DBAL layer. So use DBAL configuration:

```
$em->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger($stack); // OK
```

Instead of ORM configuration:

```
$em->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger($stack);
```

Comment: SQLLogger is deprecated as of Doctrine 2.13. We have to use middleware instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can access profiling data programmatically, see 
https://symfony.com/doc/master/profiler/profiling_data.html

If you need it in tests, see even this https://symfony.com/doc/master/testing.html#accessing-the-profiler-data